# Display pdf file from local disk in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, file-upload

I have a Laravel 5.5 app where users with administrator privileges can upload files. After they upload the files I'd like them to be able to view the file in the administrator dashboard.

I have a **DocumentController.php** that handles the file upload to the local disk:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // check to make sure user is an admin
    $request->user()->authorizeRoles('admin');

    // validate that the document is a pdf and 
    // that required fields are filled out
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'user_id' => 'required|exists:users,id', 
        'document_path' => 'required|mimes:pdf'
    ]);

    $file = $request->file('document_path');

    $path = $file->store('documents/' . $request->user_id);

    $document = Document::create([
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'file_path' => $path
    ]);

    return redirect($document->path());
}
```

This method takes the file from the form, makes sure it is a pdf and then saves the file to **storage/app/documents/{user_id}**. It then creates a Document record in the database and forwards to the URL based on the document id: **/admin/document/{ $document->id }**

That route is defined as `Route::get('/admin/document/{document}', 'DocumentController@show');`

Where in the controller I pass the document to the view:

```
public function show(Document $document, Request $request)
{
    // check to make sure user is an admin
    $request->user()->authorizeRoles('admin');

    $storagePath = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();

    return view('admin.document', compact('document', 'storagePath'));
}
```

On that page I would like to display the pdf document.

**resources/views/admin/document.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-2'>
            <a href='/admin'>< Back to admin</a>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-8'>
            {{ $document }}

            <embed src="{{ Storage::url($document->file_path) }}" style="width:600px; height:800px;" frameborder="0">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I have tried using the `$storagePath` variable and `Storage` methods but cannot get the pdf file to display within the iframe.

Using local file storage how would I display the file in the browser? Also, I've protected the route so that only admins can view the document's page but what is the best way to secure the path to the document itself?

Comment: What is the value of `$document->file_path`? And to answer your second question - to secure the documents, you need to move them outside of your webroot, or make them non-web accessible. I'd suggest the former, to avoid possible mistakes with permissions in the future. You'd then use PHP to read the file contents from the filesystem and to stream it to the browser.

Comment: `file_path` is the path on my local machine. For the needs of this application I think it's going to be best to store the files on S3. Good point about storing the documents outside of webroot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want your files to be protected (only admin can access them), then you need to create a new route and new `DocumentController` method `getDocument`

Add new route

```
Route::get('documents/pdf-document/{id}', 'DocumentController@getDocument');
```

In **DocumentController**, add

```
use Storage;
use Response;
```

Add new method that will read your pdf file from the storage and return it back

```
public function getDocument($id)
{
    $document = Document::findOrFail($id);

    $filePath = $document->file_path;

    // file not found
    if( ! Storage::exists($filePath) ) {
      abort(404);
    }

    $pdfContent = Storage::get($filePath);

    // for pdf, it will be 'application/pdf'
    $type       = Storage::mimeType($filePath);
    $fileName   = Storage::name($filePath);

    return Response::make($pdfContent, 200, [
      'Content-Type'        => $type,
      'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$fileName.'"'
    ]);
}
```

In your view you can show the document like this

```
<embed
    src="{{ action('DocumentController@getDocument', ['id'=> $document->id]) }}"
    style="width:600px; height:800px;"
    frameborder="0"
>
```

Answer (score 3):

Shorter version of that `Response::make()` from @ljubadr answer:

`return Storage::response($document->file_path)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed
src="{{ url('/filepath') }}"
style="width:600px; height:800px;"
frameborder="0">
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - where does it use any PDF file?