# laravel how to display pdf in any blade page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

> How can I display a PDF in a Laravel View like I can display a normal
>   image?
>
> The code I am using to implement an image is:

```
<div class="u-img">
    <img 
        src="image/{{ Auth::user()->photo_jpeg }}" 
        alt="profile"
    />
</div>
```

> What options/HTML-tags can I use to display a PDF?

Comment: `<embed src="pdf_file_path"/>`

Comment: @ViperTecPro   not working i also tried <iframe src="{{URL::to('/WEBSITE-FILE')}}/pdf.pdf" width="100%" height="600"></iframe> not worked

Comment: Have you checked this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/46898095/5928015 ?

Comment: What do you mean not working ? is there any error ? does file path is correct ? can you open pdf from your browser url ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro it showing empty page nothing is displayed without any error

Comment: Were you able to solve this?