# How to display pdf file from storage in view

Tags: php, laravel

I made a research on how to display pdf file in blade. And i found this answer. But what should i do in blade to display the file?

```
  $filename = 'test.pdf';
  $path = storage_path($filename); 

  return Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
      'Content-Type'
  => 'application/pdf',


  'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
```

How can i show the result(pdf) in  in blade?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display pdf file from local disk in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898095/display-pdf-file-from-local-disk-in-laravel-5)

Comment: I mean how can i show the result in <embed src= something> in blade?

Answer (score -1):

```
<iframe src="path_of_pdf_file" width ="100%" height="600px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, especially concerning `path_of_pdf_file`

Comment: "path_of_pdf_file" means local path where pdf is stored. You need to give pdf file path in src attribute.